# How do i sort a lot of lists to get a top 10 in python?

Tags: python, list

I got a .txt file filled with so many and many lines with this structure.

```
["saelyth", 17896, 96511, 4733, "0", "F00", "0", 11, 1, "ffg, ghks"]
["example", 765, 3873, 342, "000", "F63", "5", 15, 1, "ffg"]
["whatever", 158, 756, 36, "000", "000", "0", 13, 0, "ffg, jdhs"]
["okay", 12680, 64548, 4469, "000", "0CC", "1", 15, 9, "ffg"]
["randomname", 5668, 30105, 1752, "0", "360", "0", 14, 7, "ffg"]
["something", 24798, 132792, 5764, "000", "000", "0", 12, 3, "ffg"]
```

So far i've been using json.loads to load line by line. But now i want to make a top 10 of the lists (in ascending order) using the value[3] as key.

How would i do that? i was googling how sorted works but i don't think i could use it without breaking the lists and extract only that value, and then i'd have no way to display the correct lists in the Top10 print :\

I tried transforming it to a tuple but it doesnt saves the file, and no idea why.

```
    leyendotop10 = open("textfiles\estadisticas\Estadisticas.txt", "r")
    top10leido = leyendotop10.read()
    leyendotop10.close()

    print("Readed")
    atuple1 = top10leido.replace("[", "(")
    atuple2 = atuple1.replace("]\n", "), ")
    listitaglobaldetop10 = []
    listitaglobaldetop10.append(atuple2)
    print("Fixed")
    sorted(listitaglobaldetop10, key=lambda stats: stats[1])
    print("Ordered")

    grabandotop10 = open("textfiles\estadisticas\top10.txt", "a")
    grabandotop10.write(str(listitaglobaldetop10))
    grabandotop10.close()
    print("Saved")
```

Any thoughs or an easier way to do what i'm trying to do?

**Info:** IDLE 3.3.2 and the textfile contains 4300 lists.

Comment: Since they are lists and not dicts, i'd like to use any of the list, i just need to learn how to do it. So... [1], [2] or [3] would be good, after i learn how it works i'll just play with it until i suceed.

Comment: Just a warning, if you use `str` (or just `print`) to write the file then it won't be valid json, since Python uses single-quoted strings for preference whereas json only uses double-quotes. This might not matter if your code is the only thing that uses the file, of course, but you should at least be aware that although similar it's a different format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simplify this a bit. Let's say you've got your text file as shown. You can read it line by line as follows:

```
from ast import literal_eval
lines = []
with open(infile_path, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = literal_eval(line)
        lines.append(line)
```

Now you've got a list (called `lines`) of the lines in the file, and due to their structure they're already interpretable as Python types (the `literal_eval` bit interprets the text).

Now to sort them by one of the entries you can do (here I'm sorting by the index 3 entries):

```
lines.sort(key = lambda x: x[3])
```

Here I'm using a [lambda expression](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) to return the index 3 entry in each item. See the [Sorting HOW TO](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) for more details.

Once that's done you can pick out the top 10 and write them to your file:

```
with open(outfile_path, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in lines[-10:]:
        print(line, file=outfile)
```

Comment: Yeah, one of my very first thoughs when i save data is to make it interpretable, but due that i'm still learning python i didn't figured out i could use Eval to store a variable (silly me). That is really helpful :D i'm gonna test the second part of the code.

Comment: I did a print after the appended lines and its perfect so far, but then it seems it doesn't work when it gets to: lines = lines.sort(key = lambda x: x[3])

Comment: Whoops, I made a mistake. Try it without the `lines = ` part. I amended my answer.

Comment: You, sir, just won the thread :P Thanks for the heads up, i'll be playing with the code a bit until i fully understand how it works :D

Comment: Just noticed a little bit problem. It sorts is in reverse mode...?

Comment: Note: using `eval` is always a security hole if you can't guarantee safe input. If that's the case, use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @Sayleth, change to `lines.sort(key = lambda x: x[3], reverse=True)` to switch.

Answer (score 4):

```
# reading the file
with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    lines = list(json.loads(x) for x in infile)

# the important part
top_10_lines = sorted(lines, key = lambda line : line[3], reverse = True)[0:10]

# to write the top 10 file:
with open(other_filename, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in top_10_lines:
        print(json.dumps(line), file = outfile)
```

If you want, you can get fancy and use `heapq.nlargest` instead of `sorted` to get the top 10.

You can also omit the list (with or without 'nlargest'), but only if your code doesn't need to use `lines` for anything else:

```
# reading the file
with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    top_10_lines = heapq.nlargest(
        10,
        (json.loads(x) for x in infile),
        key = lambda x : x[3],
    )
```

This should use less memory, and might well be faster. Since your file is small anyway, a few hundred KB, it's probably not a big deal. For a large file from which you only need a small number of lines it will make a noticeable difference.

Comment: the second chunk of code is the right answer;,  even if you *do* need `lines` for something else, you can use `itertools.tee` to split them off.

Comment: Although the previous answer fixed my problem, I will totally test this one out and see what it can do. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @dequestarmappartialsetattr: you shouldn't really use `itertools.tee` in cases where you're going to read the whole of one "arm" before reading the other one. `list` or `tuple` is usually better in that case, because the `tee` will end up storing all the data simultaneously in memory anyway. I suppose you could worry about the case where with `tuple` you run out of memory half way through the second "arm", in which case `tee` might have freed the first half of the data by then. I think that's a pretty specific scenario that you can address if it happens.

Comment: I see, i kinda use lists for everything, but i've tried to use tuples for some things and it works nice. About itertools i gotta admit i only used combinations or permutations, i will check about the Tee one. thanks for the information.

Comment: using `tee` doesn't save space, it saves time;  you don't *need* to sort the whole list, just the top 10.  Hmm.. i suppose you don't need tee for that either; just read the file into a list, and then `heapq.nlargest` that, without sorting.

Comment: another thought, `itertools.imap(json.loads, infile)` is a somewhat nicer version of `(json.loads(x) for x in infile)` and likewise, `operator.itemgetter(3)` is a nicer version of `lambda x: x[3]`.

Comment: @dequestarmappartialsetattr: for certain values of "nice". I prefer to reach into the libraries only when they make a significant difference. Personally I prefer a comprehension over simple uses of `(i)map` and `(i)filter`. Aside from aesthetics, `operator.itemgetter(3)` would certainly be worth trying out if performance is an issue, it might shave a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.  You will need to write data to the new file.

```
def item_one(sequence):
    """Returns int(sequence[1]).
    """
    return int(sequence[1])

data = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # strip the line terminator and brackets
        line = line.strip().strip('[]')
        # make it into a list
        line = line.split(',')
        #save it for later
        data.append(line)

data.sort(key = item_one)
print data[-2:]

# or
data.sort(key = item_one, reverse = True)
print data[:2]
```

Comment: Something missing or did i miss where did you get the item_one object? it gives me this error: NameError: global name 'item_one' is not defined